# how to add 15 mins to time for extended hours

Tags: jquery

Given a start time and end time, how to generate an array of time range between these two time given.  The problem I face is when the end time extend to the next day.

**function to add 15 minutes to every given time.**

```
   function addMinutes(time, minutes) {

 var date = new Date(new Date('01/01/2017 ' + time).getTime() + minutes * 60000);
 var tempTime = ((date.getHours().toString().length == 1) ? '0' + date.getHours() : date.getHours()) + ':' +
    ((date.getMinutes().toString().length == 1) ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes());
 return tempTime;
```

}

**loop through start and end time to generate time range array with 15 mins interval**

```
start = '12:00';
end = '02:45'; //extended to the next day

var range = [start];

while(start <= end) {

    start = controller.addMinutes(start, interval);
    console.debug(start);
    range.push(start);
  }

console.debug(range);//this should contain all time range
```

> the above code, keeps looping and doesn't generate the time range only
>   if start and end time extended to  next day.

How do i solve it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it with strings. You have to use Date objects.

```js
// define the start and end date and time
var start = new Date(2018, 1, 11, 23, 00, 00);
var end = new Date(2018, 1, 12, 2, 45, 00);

var range = [];

while(start <= end) {
  var Hours = start.getHours();
  var Minutes = start.getMinutes();
  Minutes = Minutes == 0 ? "00" : Minutes;
  range.push(Hours + ":" + Minutes);
  start = new Date(start.getTime() + 15 * 60000);
}

console.log(range);
```